# Unable to save New Attribute in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento-2.0

While trying to save any new attribute in Magento 2.0 the page gets stuck showing "Please Wait". 
Please help me out in this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please reindex data first. Use bin/magento indexer:reindex to reindex all data. Then clear all caches. Then test if its working or not.

If it's not working change the browser and test.

Thank you